# Google Assistant Smart Home test suite issue

Tags: google-assistant

When I run the test suite https://smarthome-test-suite.withgoogle.com/

I get about 30% tests failed because of the error " AssertionError: State 'on' is in reported states but not in queried states: expected false to be true"
[image]

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Your Query and ReportState should be in Sync they should show same behaviour, whatever the data you are sending in Query send the Same in ReportState.